# To find and replace a text in the whole document in MS Word 2010 (including tables)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an MS Word document including a table. I am trying to find and replace text via VBA using the following code:

```
If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "<Customer_Name>"
        .Replacement.Text = TextBox1.Text
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find.Font
    .Italic = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find.Replacement.Font
    .Italic = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End If
```

This works fine for replacing all my content which is **outside** of the table. But it will not replace any of the content within the table.

Answer (score 20):

If your goal is to perform replacements in the whole documents (it looks so from the code, but it is not explicit), I would suggest you use `Document.Range` instead of the `Selection` object. Using `Document.Range` will make sure everything is replaced, even inside tables.

Also, it is more transparent to the user, as the cursor (or selection) is not moved by the macro.

```
Sub Test()
  If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
      .Text = "<Customer_Name>"
      .Replacement.Text = TextBox1.Text
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

I have used the following code and it works like charm..... for all the occurances that are found in the document.

```
  stringReplaced = stringReplaced + "string to be searched"
For Each myStoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With myStoryRange.Find
        .Text = "string to be searched"
        .Replacement.Text = "string to be replaced"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Highlight = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next myStoryRange
```