# translate javascript/jquery to vba

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, ms-word

I have this javascript/jquery code that deletes sections of a html file

```
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var d = divs.length;
for (var i = 1; i < d; i++) {
    if( $('.section'+i).innerHTML.includes("textfind")==true || $('.section'+i).innerHTML.includes("textfind2")==true){
    $('.section'+i).remove();
    }
}
```

I would like write the same function as vba code for word

I have this code so far

```
Dim i as Long
    For each objSect in ActiveDocument.sections
        if objSect.Range.Text like "textfind +i" Or "textfind2+i" then objSect.range.delete
    Next objSect
```

how would I got about deleting those particular section where i find the strings

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate the question here?? And, you want to remove html or word elements using VBA??

*EDIT* :- You can create a variable and store an array of strings in it to find and replace. (note: If you want to just clear the text then, use an empty string in place of the 'replace' string.)

Refer to this link for VBA find and replace code [VBA To find and replace a string in MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609963/vba-to-find-and-replace-a-text-in-ms-word-2010)

Comment: Yes using vba I want to do same thing as JavaScript

Comment: I think you got an solution somewhere else in the forum. If so, then please mark this question as closed/resolved

Comment: @AK0101 Don't forget to accept an answer (even if not mine!)

Answer (score 0):

RemoveTextfinders: will remove both of there elements

```
<div class="section1">textfind2</div>
<div class="section2"><input name="textfind2" value="" /></div>
```

But neither of these elements

```
<div class="section1" name="textfind2"></div>
<div class="">textfind2</div>

Sub RemoveTextfinders()
    Dim d, divs
    Set divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each d In divs
        If InStr(d.className, "section") And InStr(d.innerHTML, "textfind2") Then d.ParentNode.RemoveChild d
    Next
End If
```

**Update** I combined the two if statements they where redundant. 
InStr(d.className, "section") will evaluate to true if any of the div's class contain the "section". 
This code ran fine for me. I must be mistaken about the structure of your html.   Could you please post a sample of the html?

Comment: that did not work, also forgot to add section numbers see edited op

Comment: its html file opened in microsoft word so it doesnt have any html tags like divs, so need to use activedocument.sections vba code